# Dollar sign in Javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to parse an an element and set the area by currency.

HTML:

```
<span id="price">¥82,84</span><br/>
```

Javascript:

```
        price = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
        price = price.slice(0,1);

        if(price == "€")
        {
            area = "europe";
        }
        if(price == "£")
        {
            area = "europe";
        }
        if(price == "\$")
        {
            area == "northamerica";
        }
        if(price == "\¥")
        {
            area == "asia";
        }
```

Euro and Pounds are working, but Yen and Dollar not. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in your comparisons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using equality comparison `==` in the statements where you should use assignment operator `=`.

Answer (score 7):

`.innerHTML` might return the HTML entities `&dollar;`. Use `.textContent` or `.innerText` instead. Also, since `price` cannot be two different chars, I suggest to use nested `else if`s instead of multiple `if`s.

The error itself is located at the dollar and yuan blocks: You are using `==` instead of a plain `=`.

```
    price = document.getElementById("price").textContent; // or innerText for IE
    price = price.charAt(0); // equal to .slice(0,1);

    if(price == "€") {
        area = "europe";
    } else if(price == "£") {
        area = "europe";
    } else if(price == "$") {
        area = "northamerica";
    } else if(price == "¥") {
        area = "asia";
    } else { // Default
        area = "Unknown";
    }
```

There are two other methods:

- Switch blocks:

  ```
  switch(price) {
     case '€': case '£':
         area = 'europe';
     break;
     case '$':
         area = 'northamerica';
     break;
     case '¥'
         area = 'asia';
     break;
     default:
         area = 'unknown';
  }
  ```
- Hashes:

  ```
  var price = document.getElementById("price").textContent; //or innerText (IE)
  price = price.charAt(0);
  var priceToArea = {
       '€': 'europe',
       '£': 'europe',
       '$': 'northamerica',
       '¥': 'asia'
  };
  var area = priceToArea[price] || 'Unknown'; //Default Unknown
  ```

Comment: If you want to capture unexpected outputs, you can add `else {area = 'N/A';}` in the first block, `default: area='N/A'` in the `switch` block, or `var area = priceToArea[price] || 'N/A'` in the hash-method.

Comment: I think you missed a comma here `'$': 'northamerica'<comma>`

Comment: @ajax333221 Nicely spotted, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Further to [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9144524/171703) I would also use a switch statement for clarity:

```
switch (price)
{
    case "€":
    case "£":
        area = "europe";
        break;
    case "$":
        area = "northamerica";
        break;
    case "¥":
        area = "asia";
        break;
}
```